# Should UseLayoutRounding & SnapsToDevicePixels Be Used Always?

Tags: wpf

In my other (unrelated) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162327/displaying-errors-having-controls-after-to-move-downwards), @Meleak had `SnapsToDevicePixels` scattered throughout the code (in his answer), I found out it is used to make things look sharper. So the question, why is it not used everywhere since it will make things look better? OR are there downsides I need to be aware of? When should/shouldn't I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing that disables [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), which improves sharpness but also defeats WPF's [resolution independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_independence). It can either be a good or a bad thing, depending on what you're doing in your app, graphics-wise.

See [Pixel Snapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx) on MSDN for a complete explanation.

Comment: It disables subpixel _positionning_, not _rendering_ (a stroked path will continue to be rendered with anti-aliasing). It simply rounds components boundaries so they have integer coordinates and sizes. It doesn't defeats resolution independence either, as rounding is done _after_ converting device independent values to device space.

Comment: @Nicolas, well, it's harder to be rendered using subpixels when all your boundaries are snapped to actual pixel values... Your stroke path example would work, but e.g. straight lines and fills wouldn't. Also, since resolution independence revolves around being independent from the pixel grid, I can't see how it would be achieved when snapped to that very pixel grid. Even if rounding is performed after coord system conversion, there will probably be small differences in rendering between devices.

Comment: Yes, there will be small differences, but your application will roughly look the same in 96 or 300 dpi. That's what I mean by _resolution independence_.