# WPF Dock Panel wierd magin

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very simple dockpanel inside a border. But the dock panel seems to have a 1px margin on the right and bottom. I cant seem to get rid of it by setting the margin or the dockpanel nor by setting the padding of the border.

What exactly is causing it and how can I fix it without hacking it (I.E. negative margin on the dock panel)

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Padding="0">
            <DockPanel Background="Blue" Margin="0"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

No style defined on Border or DockPanel. Tried this on a brand new project and still seeing the white lines

Comment: That's an interesting artifact.  I pasted your exact XAML into my project and it displays as expected; no white gap.  Do you have that Border inside some other container that might be throwing off things?

Comment: Can you share more surrounding XAML? Is there a ScaleTransform applied anywhere?

Comment: @EdPlunkett thats all the xaml for that window. It is a newly created project with only one MainWindow.xaml

Comment: Can't recreate. Sorry. In fact, it won't even build as you describe it. Are you absolutely certain there's no Window element around the XAML you pasted in?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I posted the entire window's xaml. I am on Windows 7 if that matters

Comment: @Steve Thanks, the Windows version was actually my next question. Do you have a nonstandard font size or something? The usual way you get gaps like that in XAML is becasue the UI is being scaled. You could try playing with `UseLayoutRounding` and `SnapsToDevicePixels`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I never changed anything related to font size, but UseLayoutRounding="False" seems to do the trick. if you want to write up an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way you get gaps like that in XAML is becasue the UI is being scaled. If you can't find anything that might be scaling it (`RenderTransform` in a parent, OS settings such as font size, probably other stuff), you could try playing with [`UseLayoutRounding` and `SnapsToDevicePixels`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164561/should-uselayoutrounding-snapstodevicepixels-be-used-always).