# Extra character in DataGridCell when HorizontalAlingment = Center

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid. In which the contents of the cells need to be centered. But when I center the content ( via CellStyle ) - the "|" symbol appears to the right of the content. I don't know what this symbol is or how to remove it.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb0M6.png)

```
CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));

DataGrid = new DataGrid()
{
    RowHeight = _rowHeight,
    ColumnHeaderHeight = columnHeight,

    AutoGenerateColumns = false,
    CanUserAddRows = false,
    CanUserDeleteRows = false,
    CanUserReorderColumns = false,
    CanUserResizeColumns = true,
    CanUserResizeRows = false,
    CanUserSortColumns = false,
    HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column,

    Width = width,
    MaxWidth = width,
    Height = height,
    MaxHeight = height,

    SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Single,
    SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow,

    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled,
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled,

    ColumnHeaderStyle = HeaderStyle,
    CellStyle = CellStyle,

    ItemsSource = Rows,
};
```

How can i remove "|" character?

Comment: That is not a character, but just a rendering artifact. Try the UseLayoutRounding or the SnapToDevicePixels properties, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4164561/1136211.